# SceneKit to Metal migration - Euler Angle to Rotation Matrix and Z Coordinate System

Tags: ios, scenekit, glkit, metal

I am moving from scene kit api to metal api.  In have to do transforms on a node.

In scene kit i do this by simply setting

```
let camera = SCNCamera()
camera.zFar = 10000
camera.zNear = 0.1
camera.xFov = 93.299
camera.yFov = 77.65614

let cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = camera
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 10, 0)
cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(-2.degreesToRadians, 0, 0)
cameraNode.name = "CameraNode"
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

let plane = SCNPlane(width:1, height:1)
plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blueColor()
plane.firstMaterial?.doubleSided = true

let node = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
node.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 55)
node.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(90.degreesToRadians, -47.degreesToRadians, 0)
node.scale = SCNVector3Make(169, 169, 169)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

but in metal there is no way for setting eulerAngles and creating the projection transform based on xFieldOfView and yFieldOfView.  As of now i am using GLKIT of all matrix calculations

Model Matrix - here i am doing the rotation in ZYX order (because thats how the scene kit does for the provided euler angle) (using node properties)

```
var modelMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeZRotation(0)
modelMatrix = GLKMatrix4RotateY(modelMatrix, -47.degreesToRadians)
modelMatrix = GLKMatrix4RotateX(modelMatrix, 90.degreesToRadians)
modelMatrix = GLKMatrix4Translate(modelMatrix, 0, 0, 100)
modelMatrix = GLKMatrix4Scale(modelMatrix, 169, 169, 169)
```

View Matrix (using camera node properties)

```
var viewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 10, -0)
viewMatrix = GLKMatrix4RotateZ(viewMatrix, 0)
viewMatrix = GLKMatrix4RotateY(viewMatrix, 0)
viewMatrix =    GLKMatrix4RotateX(viewMatrix,-2.degreesToRadians)
```

Perspective Transform (Using camera properties)

```
let projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(77.65614, Float(1024/682.66666666666674), 0.1, 10000)
```

here 1024 and 682.66666666666674 is my views's height and width.

The scene kit's output and metal output is not the same.  for some reason the plane is always rendered on top half of the view in metal kit but in scene kit it is rendered on the bottom half (which is what i wanted) and adjusting the yFieldOfView in metal changes whether the plane is rendered in top half or bottom half and also the scaling and rotation of the output plane in metal view is different from the scene kit.

My Question is :
1. SceneKit coordinate system uses +z in front and -z at back.  Whereas Metal uses -z in front and +z at back. 
In metal, will simply multiplying all the z rotation and translation values by -1  fix it?

2. How to do euler angle in metal.   I went through couple of links and stack overflow answers and my understanding is that euler angle is the rotation on each axis and multiplied in specific order.   Here i am multiplying in zyx order because thats how scene kit uses it.
3. How do you generate perspectiveMatrix with xFieldOfView and yFieldOfView.  I am using GLKMatrix for all matrix transformations. It doesn't have any function like scene kit does.  I am passing viewWidth/viewHeight as a value to aspect.    How does one generate aspect from xFieldOfView and yFieldOfView. Is that as simple as this 
   aspect = xFieldOfView/yFieldOfView or is it something different.  There is this library https://github.com/nicklockwood/VectorMath/blob/master/VectorMath/VectorMath.swift
   which calculates the aspect using xFieldOfView/yFieldOfView
4. when i am creating the plane in scene kit i am setting the size of plane as follows
   let plane = SCNPlane(width:1, height:1)

Is the size matter in metal? In metal the clip space is from -1 to 1 along all axis.   And In metal u can set the size of the plane by generating the plane vertices accordingly i have tried generating the vertices from -1 to 1 (here the width and height is 2.)  and -0.5 to 0.5 (here the width and height is 1).  But it doesn't give me right result.

5. In what order does the scene kit does the rotation, scaling and translation.  I couldn't find any information related to this in apple documentation.

Basically i want to port my scene kit code to metal with same output.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Metal's clip space runs from 0..1 in z, contrary to GL. You probably don't want to use GLKit's matrix utility for building your projection matrix. Once you have that sorted out, I'd recommend multiplying your matrices by some sample vertices by hand to ensure they wind up where you expect in clip space.

Comment: thanks @warrenm  bought your book it was great.